# How to change a characters separated by a colon into an integer?

Tags: r

I have a vector of number that I am using to subset entries in a list. Many of the list items are a single number, but others are a range. Currently, they are all saved as characters and I'd like to convert them to numbers. I've used as.integer() and, but when I do this I get a message saying "NAs introduced by coercion."

My question is can I convert a number range ("5:20") that has the character type into an integer range (5:20)?
I would like to use this to subset a data frame like so: my_dataframe[5:20].

I am very open to taking a different approach entirely if that would be more efficient.

Examples below:

```R
x <- c("1", "2", "3", "4:5", "6:9", "10")

as.integer(x)

[1] NA
Warning message:
In x %>% unlist() %>% as.integer() : NAs introduced by coercion
```

Comment: If you don't mind warnings, a base R one-liner is ```Reduce(`:`, strsplit(x, ":"))```. (This is not in the dupe, btw.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are 100% sure that the elements of `x` are and will always be of the form you specified, then you could `parse` and `eval` each element:

```r
x %>% map(~ eval(parse(text = .x))) %>% unlist()
```

```
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

However, in general, evaluating variable strings is not a good idea (in particular for security reasons).

Comment: Good to know about the security issues. Thank you very much!